# Going back to previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two activities,  How is it possible to go back to a previous activity.

What code do I need to go back to previous activity

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you started the new activity with

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

puts the SecondActivity in front and the FirstActivity in the backstack. To go back to the FirstActivity, put this in your second activity.

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start the activity with result like below :

**From 1st Activity :**

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class),requestCode);
```

You can finish the activity with required intents :

**From 2nd Activity :**

```
// Optional if you want to pass values from second activity to first
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("key","any_value");
setResult(RESULT_OK,data);

// Just finish
finish();
```

Refer the below link for more information like `onActivityResult` callback and more
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

**1st Method**

If you are using `Intent` then make sure you don't call `finish();` method after using the following code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

By this code, the Back Button you created will do its work and go to previous Activity.

And also don't override the `onBackPressed()` method in Activity.

**2nd Method**

There is another way that you can achieve this by setting Home Button to go to specific Activity, For that, you have to create Back Button in Action Bar in `onCreate()` method.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

And in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you have to add the following,

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.yourapplication.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_second_activity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.yourapplication.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.yourapplication.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**using intent**

```
  intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**Or you can use onBackPressed() if the activity added to backstack**

```
onBackPressed();
```